# MySQL add days to column field if on weekday

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a parameter called pmday which I want to, when it is enetered, check if the day is on a saturday or sunday, and, if so, show the monday after.

I am relatively new to mySQL and I am running a SELECT statement to use pmday in other ways. Can I create a column which will show the monday after, only if the day falls on a weekend?

Here is an example of what I have been trying (and failing) to do. Im not sure if this is just a problem of me not knowing how, functions within select statements not being allowed, or general formatting and use of commas.

Thank you!

```
SELECT
    pmday AS EnteredDate,
    IF DateFormat(pmday, '%W') = 'Saturday' then
         Date_Add('pmday', INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS FollowingMonday
    Else If  DateFormat(pmday, '%W') = 'Sunday'  then
         Date_Add('pmday', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS FollowingMonday
    END IF;
```

Comment: If you're not storing data in a table, then MySQL is probably the wrong tool for the job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    pmday AS EnteredDate,
    CASE Date_Format(pmday, '%W')
        WHEN 'Saturday' THEN Date_Add(pmday, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN Date_Add(pmday, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        ELSE pmday
    END AS FollowingMonday
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have gone around in circles for who knows how long!!! I'm glad to know I wasnt totally off, but who knows how long, if ever, until I would have gotten it

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement its wrong..

This worked for me...

```
set @pmday = current_date;


select 
    if(Date_Format(@pmday, '%W') = 'Saturday',
   Date_Add(@pmday, INTERVAL 2 DAY), 

    if(Date_Format(@pmday, '%W') = 'Sunday',
   Date_Add(@pmday, INTERVAL 1 DAY), @pmday)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

--- find the next monday if selected date is saturday or sunday

```
set @pmday = "2012-10-20";
select if(
           DAYOFWEEK( @pmday) = 1 or DAYOFWEEK( @pmday) = 7
           , DATE_ADD( @pmday, INTERVAL (9 - IF(DAYOFWEEK( @pmday)=1, 8, DAYOFWEEK( @pmday))) DAY) 
           , @pmday
          );
```